# I wants to build my react app but getting Error TypeError: MiniCssExtractPlugin is not a constructor at module.exports

Tags: reactjs, npm, build

D:\React JS Projects\React Facts\reactfacts\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js:664
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
^

TypeError: MiniCssExtractPlugin is not a constructor
at module.exports (D:\React JS Projects\React Facts\reactfacts\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js:664:9)
at Object. (D:\React JS Projects\React Facts\reactfacts\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\build.js:58:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

Answer (score 0):

There is bug in versio 2.5.0, you could do some workaround by changing import to this one:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin').default
```

Here you have bug report on github https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/896